# Could I make a persistent Ubuntu USB drive from Debian?

Tags: debian, persistence, mkusb

A lot of online tutorials say that I need to use mkusb on ubuntu to make a persistent ubuntu usb. Could I use mkusb on debian to make a persistent ubuntu usb?

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is about Debian and not Ubuntu. Expect it to be closed as off topic. As for an answer: why not? Have you tried to install mksub?

Comment: Yes you can use mkusb on debian to make a persistent ubuntu usb. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian)